# Duplicate question for other kind of answer

Tags: discussion

I am looking for comparison of actor and agent systems. I came across this question: [What is the difference between actors (Akka) and agents (JADE) in distributed systems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15295504/what-is-the-difference-between-actors-akka-and-agents-jade-in-distributed-sy) that already asks about it, however in answers I see only comparison of software (JADE vs Akka) and not concepts (agent vs actor).

I am looking for answer like: Agent can do X, while actor cannot, but actor can do Y, while agent cannot (instead of: JADE can do X, while Akka cannot, but Akka can Y while JADE cannot).

What should I do?

Comment: Sound like your quesition is too broad, asking for 3rd party resources respectively.

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: Check out the help center and meta over on the software recs stack exchange. They are very strict, but you might be able to formulate an on-topic question over there.

Comment: @spam That question might be _off topic_ nowadays (and we already ´closed it for that reason now). It was asked in 2013, when the rules weren't that strict. So you cannot really ask here for such comparison of these systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do your own research and come back to SO when you have concrete questions.

You are explicitly looking for an answer that gives essentially unbounded list of things. This is way too broad for any of the Stack Exchange sites.

Existence of an old question on the similar topic does not make new one on-topic now. The old question may have slipped the rules in the past or some rules change/got stricter over time.

Some variants of the question *may* be on topic either on [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help) (if you more interested about concepts) or [Software Recomendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help) (for more of product choice variation). Question will need to have significantly more information to meet the bar for either of the sites.

If you are looking for getting that question on SO - if you have a particular problem you need to solve with actors (or agents) but you only know way to do with the other kind it probably would be on-topic. Just asking for differences is not on-topic.